# What would be the proper latin terminology for half-human anatomy configurations?

Tags: creature-design, mythical-creatures, fauna, anatomy

Many half-human mythological creatures follow a few common anatomical schemes.

- Some consist of an animal with a human face, such as the sphinx, naga
  and manticore.
- Some consist of a human anterior and animal posterior, such as the
  satyr, faun, ipotane and mermaid.
- Some consist of an animal whose head has been replaced with a human
  torso, such as the centaur.

Using latin as the source language a la Linnaean taxonomy, what would be a logical terminology for unambiguously distinguishing between these body types?

EDIT: The answers I've been getting have been really great. I was inspired to do some more research and discovered some Latin, Greek and "New Latin" vocabulary as an alternative to linguistically correct terms.

- *Semifer* and *Semihomo*, Latin synonyms for half-beast half-human
  hybrids.
- *Theropod*, or "beast-footed", referring to theropod dinosaurs, but could easily be repurposed to distinguish satyrs, fauns, ipotanes, mermaids, cilophytes, etc. In these hybrids the body sections are joined at the pelvis.
- *Therocephalian*, "beast-headed", referring to a suborder of eutheriodont therapsids, but could easily be repurposed to
  distinguish animal-headed Egyptian and Vedic deities, minotaurs,
  werewolves, reverse mermaids, etc. In these hybrids the head is
  animal and the body is humanoid.
- *Anthro(po)cephalus*, "human-headed", used for a variety of species names, but could easily be repurposed to distinguish sphinxes, naga,
  shedu, lamasu, etc. In these hybrids the head is human and the body
  is animal.
- *Cephalothorax inversus*, of my own coinage, could refer to centaurs, khepri, etc. The phrase works by analogy: where a cephalothorax is a
  torso with a head and face in the chest, the inversion is a torso
  sprouting from where the head and face would be. In these hybrids the
  head of one parent is replaced with the torso of the other; unlike
  the theropods the join is between pelvis and clavicle.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Upper part humans or Semisohominum - from Semisos meaning half and Hominum meaning human. This includes the species of;

- Centeroids or Semisohominum Equus which includes the subspecies; Centaur or [Semisohominum Equus Caballus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centaur) and Onocentaur or [Semisohominum Equus Asinus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onocentaur)
- Faunus or [Semisohominum Capra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faun)
- Harpys or [Semisohominum Aves Aegypius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harpy)
- Merfolk or [Semisohominum Craniata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mermaid)
- Naga or [Semisohominum Serpentes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C4%81ga)

Human-headed or Maximobestia - from Maxime meaning mostlyand Bestia meaning animal. This includes the species of;

- Seamen or [Maximobestia Craniata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atargatis)
- Manticore or [Maximobestia Leo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manticore)
- Dogfolk or [Maximobestia Canis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penghou)
- Sirpents or [Maximobestia Serpentes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhulong_(mythology))

Human with animal head or Maximohominum - from Maxime meaning mostly and Hominum meaning human. This includes the species of;

- Doghead or [Maximohominum Familiarus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cynocephaly)
- Minotaur or [Maximohominum taurus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minotaur)

Human with some animal parts or Bestiahominum - from Bestia meaning animal and Hominum meaning human. This includes the species of;

- Adlet or [Bestiahominum Cruris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adlet)
- Angeloids or Bestiahominum Penna which includes the subspeices; Angel or
  [Bestiahominum Penna Columbidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angel) and Fairy or [Bestiahominum
  Penna Cimex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairy)
- Oni or [Bestiahominum Cornu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oni)
- Gorgon or [Bestiahominum Anguis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorgon)
- Kemonomimi or [Bestiahominum Pars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kemonomimi)

Comment: I'm in awe at this answer and I think it should be the one marked as correct.

Comment: Centaurs and satyrs/mermaids aren't arranged in the same way. The latter is half and half, while the former is an animal body with the head replaced by a human torso. What would be a reasonable way to distinguish this? Or, for that matter, reversed versions thereof?

Comment: Very nicely done TrEs

Comment: I promise that the puns are not intended.

Comment: But the latin word for "human being"" is "homo", not "hominum". And the latin word for "human" (the adjective) is "humanus".

Comment: @celtschk I'm not going to lie and say I speak Latin, I used google translate (which can be unreliable) and Freelang

Comment: There is a Latin SE I do beleive.

Comment: @JDługosz I might just have to join that

Comment: But no *tlhIngan Hol* :(

Comment: How is Bestiahominum a portmanteau of Bestia and **Pars**?

Comment: @Annonymus that was a mistake I must have missed, thank you

Comment: Is there a reason for the "meaning meaning" in every full sentences? (ESL here, not sure if it's voluntary or not).

Comment: @SpaceLizard typo

Answer (score 7):

As a native speaker of a romance language, I'll vouch for [Semi](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/semi-)-[humanus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/humanus) as an umbrella term for all those body types.

If you want to make that into a phylum or some other taxonomical level, contract it by dropping the -, making it Semihumanus.

If you allow for a mix with greek, Semi[antropos](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/antropo) will also do.

Now, for each body type:

Human head, animal body: Humanocaput (from "humanus" and ["caput"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/caput) which means "head" or "top"). Again, if you allow for some greek mixing, you can have ["ops"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BD%A4%CF%88) ("face") instead of "caput": Humanops.

Half human, half animal body: Animumanus ("animal" is originally a latin word) (can also switch this one with Semihumanus).

Human body, animal head: Animocaput (or Animops if you allow for some greek).

Append a name having to do with each animal for a complete species name. For example, the Minotaur can be Animocaput [taurus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/taurus).

Comment: What about distinguishing more finely between a satyr/mermaid body and centaur body? The former is mathematically half and half (what would be the appropriate adjective for "reverse" I wonder?), while the latter replaces one half's head with another half's entire torso connected at the pelvis/clavicle (pelviclavicle? pelavicle? pelvicle?).

Comment: @Renan in greek it would be 'Hemianthropos' (ημιάνθρωπος). like hemisphere = half shpere.

Comment: Actually I think "Humanimus" would sound better than "Animumanus".